# Deletion of folder inside an archive folder that do not contain .zip extension

Tags: batch-file

I have an archive folder where a script runs and places .zip files. Sometimes folders that do not contain the .zip extension are also placed inside the archive folder(it does not contain any extension. just a normal folder) and I need to delete them using batch script.

Lets say I have the archive folder on my desktop
C:\Users\Mila\Desktop\archive.I need to delete folders inside this archive folder which does not have any extension or which are not of .zip extension.

I am very new to Batch script and need your support in deleting the folders that do not have a .zip extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%# in ('dir /a:d /b^|findstr /i /e /v ".zip"') do (
  echo  rd /s /q "%%~#"
)
```

leave only `rd /s /q "%%~#"` if there are the folders that you need to delete.